# SQL Set-Comparision Operators ANY and IN difference

Tags: sql, database, predicate

I have a basic SQL question. To be able to explain it correctly.I'll give the schema of them .

`Sailors(sid:integer,sname:string,rating:integer)` (sid is a primary key.)

Now, the query is *"Find sailors whose rating is greater than some sailor called Horatio"* (there will be more than one Horatio since,sname is not a primary key)

The answer is  :

```
SELECT *
FROM Sailors S
WHERE S.rating >ANY (SELECT S2.rating
                        FROM Sailors S2
                        WHERE S2.sname="HORATIO")
```

I wonder,Could I use IN instead of ANY ? IF I dont, What differs ? Is there anyone to help me ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You couldn't use IN in with this subquery, because:

1. When you say `> ANY`, it returns those rows from outer query where the rating is higher than the rating of ANY of the ratings returned by the subquery.
2. If you would use `IN`, then it would return only those sailors who have the same rating as any of the sailor with name Horatio.

Notice that the first query may return sailors with name 'Horatio', because one sailor with a name 'Horatio' may have higher rating than another sailor with name 'Horatio'.

Also, `ANY` returns `FALSE` if subquery returns no rows.

**Edit** Ok, I didn't understand your question. You can't use `< > =` etc. operators with `IN`, they can only be used with `ANY`, `SOME` and `ALL`.

Take a look here for more information: [Tim Hall about ANY, SOME and ALL](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/all-any-some-comparison-conditions-in-sql.php)

Comment: thanks for such a reply. I think I dont understant just a point of your answer. I want to use >IN not only IN. Even if I use >IN, it still returns only those sailors who have the same rating as any of the sailor with name Horatio ?

Comment: Thanks again for insta reply. : )

Comment: @Eday Ok, I see what your point is now. You can't use `> < =` etc. with `IN` - check my edited answer.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can use `in` for this, but you can use `exists`:

```
select *
from Sailors S
where
    exists (
        select *
        from Sailors S2
        where S2.sname = 'HORATIO' and S.rating > S2.Rating
    )
```

Comment: @Eday You can't use `IN` because then the meaning of the query would change... You would have to change the subquery and as a result you would get a query that is harder to understand. In fact, what Roman Pekar is proposing, is how actually the `> ANY` will be expanded, as Tim Hall mentions in the article I have provided link to in my answer.

Comment: @PrzemyslawKruglej, What is the transition to english  of query if I only change the >ANY to >IN ? Could you explain it ?

Comment: @Eday You **can't** use `> IN`, such syntax is incorrect in Oracle and your query will not be executed. You can only use `> < =` etc. with `ANY`, `SOME` or `ALL`.

Comment: @PrzemyslawKruglej I'm so greathful to your replies.Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you want to use the `IN` (set inclusion) operator in this case. You'd need to find either an appropriate set of ratings or set of names. The search conditions for those sets would be the same as that of the desired result, so why bother?

The `ANY`, `SOME`, `ALL` operators demonstrate the high redundancy nature of the SQL language (not a desirable feature) i.e. the same result can always be achieved using many constructs, you never *need* to use `ANY`, `SOME`, `ALL`. Indeed, `ANY` and `SOME` are synonyms!

p.s. For interest, here's an alternative approach:

```
SELECT *
  FROM Sailors S
 WHERE S.rating > ( SELECT MIN( S2.rating )
                      FROM Sailors S2
                     WHERE S2.sname = 'HORATIO' );
```